# Limiting and formatting a JTextfield 

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, textfield

I have a `JTextfield` where a user enters a "social security number". The SSN has 9 digits and 2 dashes for a total of 11 characters.

How do I limit the `JTextField` to 11 characters and also have 2 dashes in the textfield at the 4<sup>th</sup> and 7<sup>th</sup> position of the 11 characters?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use :  [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html)

See this for more help : [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Also this might help : [MaskFormatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html)

Here is a sample snippet :

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("####-###-####");
```

**EDIT :**

After some research I found out that a *DocumentFilter* would do things better,

See this for more details : [Implementing a Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)